# boot problem with ubuntu 13.10 or 14.04 on linux

Tags: boot

When I start my computer, it shows me a list of three options: "Ubuntu", "advanced options for Ubuntu", "System Setup" and when I click on Ubuntu to start the screen in most cases just turns purple for a indefinite period of time and in a very small percentage of cases it boots normally.

What's my problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Add your hardware specifications to your question and try to start with the [`nomodeset` parameter](http://askubuntu.com/a/162076/265974)

Answer (score 0):

Try a quick re install of Ubuntu along side your old system. Copy the old data from your other system over and use that system instead.